How to rotate an object towards another object in unity?
How to gradually rotate an object towards another object in unity?
I tried using transform.lookAt(), in rotates object instantly, but i need to rotate it slower. Also I need to rotate camera, but player should save control over it. What can i do?

See Quaternion.RotateTowards.

how to rotate camera? can you explain that?

Use Quaternion.Slerp function to do it.
public Transform target;  // The object to rotate towards
public float rotationSpeed = 2.0f;  // Rotation speed

void Update()
{
    if (!target)
        return;

    Vector3 direction = target.position - transform.position;
    Quaternion targetRotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(direction);

    // Slerp from current rotation to the target rotation
    transform.rotation = Quaternion.Slerp(transform.rotation, targetRotation, rotationSpeed * Time.deltaTime);
}


This will gradually aproach the target, slowing down the closer it gets. If you want linear motion then make the last value in the Slerp funtion be a variable increasing by DeltaTime from 0 to 1.
